# Can't Get Powershell to assign an array over a certain size

Tags: powershell, types, int32

So, I'm trying to create a powershell script that "benchmarks" the speed of GPG using various size files. The part in specific that is causing me trouble is this:

```
1 $temppath="$($env:Temp)\"
...
4 Measure-Command {$bytes= 10000MB
5 [System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]$rng = New- Object.System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider
6 $rndbytes = New-Object byte[] $bytes
7 [System.Io.File]::WriteAllBytes("$($temppath)\test.txt", $rndbytes)} | Select-Object -OutVariable gentime | Out-Null;
```

When `$bytes >~ 1.5GB` (I use 10000MB to test it), I get an error that, If I'm understanding what's going on correctly, corresponds to the fact that the byte array is indexed by a variable of type `int32`. The specific error is this:

```
New-Object : Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "10485760000", for "Byte[]" to type "System.Int32": "Cannot convert value "10485760000" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.""
At line:6 char:13
+ $rndbytes = New-Object byte[] $bytes
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Is there a way to force powershell to index $rndbytes, when the object is created, with an index of type `int64` or `uint64`? If that's not the issue, I'd love to be shown and have what's exactly going wrong explained.

Do note, if you use, for example `$bytes=1000MB` (or write `$bytes=1GB`), the code works perfectly. I suspect I'm hitting a wall at `$bytes.index > 2^31 -1`  or so.

Thanks for the help~!!

Comment: No, an array cannot exceed `[int]::MaxValue` in length. Output in batches

Comment: Dang, that's unfortunate. So just create multiple arrays and process them in batches?

Comment: Create a small buffer array (4KB for example) and then write in chunks of that size until you've reached your desired file size

Comment: Time to learn how to do that in powershell then. Do you happen to know if `[System.Io.File]::WriteAllBytes` overwrites data, or appends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, arrays in .NET cannot exceed 2^31-1 items in length, because the index value used for arrays is `[int]` - the max value of which is 2^31-1.

It's not really a problem, because buffering 2 billion items *in memory* is terribly inefficient anyways - if you want 10GB of random data, you generate and write it to disk in *chunks* instead:

```
# Set file size
$intendedSize = 10GB

# Create output buffer
$buffer = [byte[]]::new(4KB)

# Create RNG
$rng = [System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create()

# Create temp file, open writable filestrem
$tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() |Get-Item
$fileStream = $tempFile.OpenWrite()

do {
    # Fill buffer, write to disk, rinse-repeat
    $rng.GetBytes($buffer)
    $fileStream.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
} while($fileStream.Length -lt $intendedSize)

# Dispose if filestream + RNG
$fileStream.Dispose()
$rng.Dispose()
```

`4KB` is ususally a good general buffer size on Windows, since 4KB is the default cluster size on NTFS volumes and most modern CPUs have L1 cache sizes divisible by 4KB

Comment: What is the difference between `$rng = [System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create()` and `$rng = new [System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]()` and `[System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]$rng = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider` ?  In all honesty, I'm very new to Powershell, I've only really used it for very basic things before this. Also, is Powershell very similar to C#? It seems like it is, and if it is, I might just undertake learning to use C# as a way to supplement my Powershell abilities

Comment: @Shinaolord `$rng = new [TypeName]()` is not valid PowerShell. `New-Object TypeName` is essentially the same as `[TypeName]::new()`, but since the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` exposed a static `Create()` method, the author probably intended for users to use that - so that's what I used :-) PowerShell shares the same underlying base class library as C# (`.NET`) and some syntax element are heavily "borrowed" from C#, but they two distrinct languages.

Comment: I just didn't see the ::Create() method when I looked at microsoft's documentation page for RNGCryptoServiceProvider, so I wasn't sure (:. I really only know Mathematica and less so matlab, and have dabbled in C++ and Python, but by no means am I knowledgeable in those languages. Thanks for the help!